# Union and intersection of closed and open sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My book gives a proposition but doesn t demonstrate it. It gives only examples. I would like a formal demonstration without using any particular example.

1. the union of finite number or a series of open sets is an open set. The intersection of a finite number of open sets is an open set, but it is not always true if we consider a series of open sets.
2. the intersection of finite number or a series of closed sets is a closed set. The union of a finite number of closed sets is a closed set, but it is not always true if we consider a series of closed sets.

I started demonstrating that the union of infinite closed sets it is not always closed, but to end the demonstration i need to prove that is not always true that the insersection of infinite open sets is open. It seems all concatenated

Comment: An intersection of open sets is exactly the complement of a union of closed sets.

Comment: I used De Morgan Laws

Comment: Then if you demonstrated that an infinite union of closed sets is not necessarily closed you also demonstrated (implicitly) that an infinite intersection of open sets is not necessarily open. Just take the complements.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do a strictly formal argument,  because sometimes an infinite union of closed sets is closed. Similarly an intersection of infinitely many opens.

So, in $\Bbb R$, with the usual metric, here's a counterexample:   set $\mathscr U_n=(x-\dfrac 1n,x+\dfrac 1n)$.  Then $\bigcap_n\mathscr U_{n\in\Bbb N}=\{x\}$ is not open.

And, for $a\lt b-1$, let $\mathscr C_n=[a+\dfrac 1n,b]$.  And $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\mathscr C_n=(a,b]$ is not closed.